# Use of Scala's Parsers repsep to split the String

Tags: regex, scala

Been trying to parse the following string using Scala parser combinators

```
--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
Content-Type: application/http 
Some stuff in here    

--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=changeset_77162fcd-b8da-41ac-a9f8-9357efbbd

Some other stuff here
```

Want to get the following out of it:

**Group1**

```
--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
Content-Type: application/http 
Some stuff in here
```

**Group2**

```
--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=changeset_77162fcd-b8da-41ac-a9f8-9357efbbd

Some other stuff here
```

I wrote the following using repsep but getting an error when I run it on the same input.

```
def getListOfRequests: Parser[List[String]] = repsep(getBatchModules, newLineSeparator)

def getBatchModules: Parser[String] = """(?s)--batch_.+?(?=--batch.*)""".r
```

And the error is:

> failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but`-' found
>
> --batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
>
> ^

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--batch_.+?(?=--batch|$)
```

Use this as the last `--batch` might be the end of string.So give it an alternative too.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/18

Comment: Turns out that it was the delimiter I was using for repetition causing the error. Your answer is correct anyway. Thanks!